# Stackdriver log grouping ignoring in the monitored resource definition

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-stackdriver

We've set up a "parent-child" relationship for the logging of our system as per [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/writing-application-logs#related-app-logs) documentation. We're also extracting the `traceId` for the `X-Cloud-Trace-Context` header using the format defined [here](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/troubleshooting#force-trace).

The logs are grouped nicely in the Stackdriver console when dealing with only one service, but a trace can span multiple services. The behaviour we're seeing is the child logs from all services are bundled with the request log, even if we filter the view via the console. I would have thought that the resource definition should have helped filter this view in the console? i.e. If we filtered to only see service B, we shouldn't see child logs associated with service A?

Here's a snippet of code that constructs the parent and child

```
import (
    "cloud.google.com/go/logging"
    "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/monitoredres"
    "os"
    "time"
)

//ParentLogger constructs a logger to bundle child log lines to
func ParentLogger(client *logging.Client) *logging.Logger {
    initParentLoggerOnce.Do(func() {
        commonResource := &monitoredres.MonitoredResource{
            Labels: map[string]string{
                "module_id":  os.Getenv("GAE_SERVICE"),
                "project_id": os.Getenv("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"),
                "version_id": os.Getenv("GAE_VERSION"),
            },
            Type: "gae_app",
        }
        parentLogger = client.Logger(
            "log_parent",
            logging.CommonLabels(map[string]string{}),
            logging.CommonResource(commonResource),
        )

    })
    return parentLogger
}

//ChildLogger constructs a logger representing individual log lines
func ChildLogger(client *logging.Client) *logging.Logger {
    initChildLoggerOnce.Do(func() {
        commonResource := &monitoredres.MonitoredResource{
            Labels: map[string]string{
                "module_id":  os.Getenv("GAE_SERVICE"),
                "project_id": os.Getenv("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"),
                "version_id": os.Getenv("GAE_VERSION"),
            },
            Type: "gae_app",
        }

        childLogger = client.Logger(
            "log_child",
            logging.CommonLabels(map[string]string{}),
            logging.CommonResource(commonResource),
        )
    })
    return childLogger
}

//LogRequest posts the parent request log to stackdriver
func (l *gcpRequestLogger) LogRequest() error {
    var rSize int64 = 0 //simplified for stack overflow post
    rStatus := 200 //simplified for stack overflow post

    //
    traceID, spanID, sampled := deconstructTraceContext(l.r.Header.Get("X-Cloud-Trace-Context"))
    l.parentLogger.Log(logging.Entry{
        HTTPRequest: &logging.HTTPRequest{
            Request:      l.r,
            Latency:      time.Since(l.start),
            ResponseSize: rSize,
            Status:       rStatus,
            RemoteIP:     l.r.RemoteAddr,
        },
        Timestamp:    time.Now().UTC(),
        Severity:     l.severity,
        Trace:        traceID,
        SpanID:       spanID,
        Payload:      l.requestLogPayload,
        TraceSampled: sampled,
    })
    return nil
}
```

While we could start a new trace per request on a microservice for useful request log grouping but we'd then lose the nice global view in Stackdriver Trace (not to mention the logs correlated to the trace). Have we done something wrong, or is this a gap in the way Stackdriver Logging working?

UPDATE:
  Added image of behaviour we're seeing. The last group of logs were not expected as they were generated our `config` service and in this view I'm filtering by the `support-portal` service.
[image]

Comment: Can you show us a (sanitized) screenshot of an **expanded** log entry you are getting and explain what you'd expect instead?

Comment: The behavior you report seems  expected, with all logs from different services grouped under a same log request entry since they share the same `TraceId`. But you should be able to further filter logs by service.

Comment: Agreed, it's the part where, when filtering by service, we're still getting logs pulled in logged against a different resource. I've added a screenshot of the behaviour we're seeing.